# Can multiple add/delete of document to an index make it inconsistent?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

For a use-case, I'll need to add and remove multiple documents to an elastic search index. My understanding is that the tf-idf or BM25 scores are affected by the frequencies that are calculated using the postings list (?)... But, if I add and remove many documents in a day, will that affect the document/word statistics?

I've already went though a lot of API's but my untrained eyes could not locate if this is the case, or if there's a way for me to force ElasticSearch to update/recompute the index every day or so...

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"The IDF portion of the score can be affected by deletions and modifications" the rest should be fine... (Igor Motov)

Link to discussion:
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/can-multiple-add-delete-of-document-to-an-index-make-it-inconsistent/137030